# Using python to add a list to a postion in a csv file

Tags: python

Im rather new to modifying csv files, but I need to add a list as a row to particular position in a  file, such as position H. I initially opened a file for reading and then set it to a variable, and for the length of that variable append the ith element of my list to position H of that file or list. I'm very confused on executing this though so anyones help would be very well appreciated.

Comment: it would help if you post a code snippet of what you already have

Comment: Typically, inserting things into existing files require rewriting the whole part from the insertion to the end.

Answer (score 1):

You would read in the CSV as a list of lines and insert the new line and then output the list as a new CSV file.

```
lines = csv.read('my_file.csv')
lines.insert(rowIndex, newRow)
csv.write(lines, 'my_new_file.csv')
```

That's pseudo-code but that's how it should work.

Comment: With small files this works fine. With several GB of data, you'd need to get a bit more advanced. Still, without more info, this is the best answer one can hope for. :)

Comment: With a large file you would still have to re-assemble the file into a new CSV, but you wouldn't read it all in, you would copy the lines right away and when you hit `rowIndex` you would insert `newRow` and then continue copying lines from the original file.

Comment: This is the snippet of code i have as of right now. I'm just having trouble implementing my list to a specific position.  writer = csv.writer(open("data.csv", "wb"))
    writer.writerows(outcomes)
    filed = open("data.csv")
    outcomes = filed.readlines()
    outcomes.close()